# Nuproj alternatives for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuproj

We have a legacy C# and C++ solution (web services, web app, OWIN and Nancy) that was built with Visual Studio 2013.  We now must use Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.  The solution has a .nuproj file that we were using with [the open source nuproj github repo](https://github.com/nuproj/nuproj) that has been archived and is unsupported in VS 2019.  The nuproj authors have not supplied any help (from what I can see) on how to convert or migrate nuproj to a VS 2019 format.

I am wondering if anyone knows the quickest way to get this working?

Alternatives would also be appreciated.

I read:

- [Quickstart: Create and publish a NuGet package using Visual Studio (.NET Standard, Windows only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli), but I was hoping not to install .NET Core on my company laptop yet.
- [Automating creating NuGet package as part of build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180904/automating-creating-nuget-package-as-part-of-build-process), but I see that is eight years old.
- Internet searches about csproj self-pack and dotnet pack, but again, I do not want .NET Core right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing straightforward. I will retool and use NAnt.